# Add gradient color scheme to Joypy plots

Tags: python, histogram, ridgeline-plot

I was wondering that if anyone has ever tried to use a gradient colour scheme for each plot using `joypy` (not the whole joyplot color gradient like [this](https://sbebo.github.io/img/joypy/output_17_0.png))?

If someone has some pointers, please tell me. I tried using `matplotlib.patches` following an [example](https://pradhanphy.blogspot.com/2014/06/filling-between-curves-with-color.html) here, but my plots somehow disappear!! I do not have any solution for this, yet.

If someone is unfamiliar with `joypy` follow this [link](https://sbebo.github.io/posts/2017/08/01/joypy/) for a general idea.

Additional information added:

```
## What I do not want, can be done using the following code
joypy.joyplot(data, ylim='own', overlap = 0.2, bins = 50,
              alpha = 0.35, grid=True, colormap = cm.Blues)
### Unnecessary code not shown
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look to colormaps for matplotlib https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

Comment: Sorry, it is not that easy. Additional information added.

Comment: You just have to map the y values to a colormap